# is cffile action="rename" === fileMove in CFScript?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Does `fileMove()` do exactly the same thing as `<cffile action="rename">`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No they are different. There is no CFML Script function available to do a file Rename. So, the above use case is just a trick to achieve file rename.

You have to specify the same source and destination folder but change the file name in <destination>.

```
filemove("c:\userdata\files\myFile.docx", "c:\userdata\files\yourFile.docx");
```

Comment: fileMove() is not restricted to CFScript, it's just a function, so one can just go `<cfset fileMove(src, dest)>`. Have removed your reference to CFScript in your answer, plus fixed a syntax error. Other than that, perfect answer in my opinion. Upvoted.

Comment: @AdamCameron I agree with you & thank you for the edit. It looks better now.

Comment: so they are different, how?  cffile action = "rename" description:
Renames or moves a file on the server. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7377.html  I have a feeling that they do the same thing.

Comment: It handles both requirements or moving and renaming (which are the same thing, and there's no need for two different options for `<cffile>`). You specifically asked whether it was "`===`", and it's not. But it's completely analogous. @Sanjeev was pointing out that `fileMove()` is intended for moving files (which is just a rename with a different path), so is not the same in intent as `<cffile action="rename">`, but amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @AdamCameron Linux uses `mv` (move) for both moving and renaming, so I'm just trying to find out if `<cffile action="rename">` === `<cffile action="move">` === `fileMove()` in CF.  You could say the "intent" is different, but other then that, aren't they doing the exact same thing?

Comment: @Henry, the info is right there in front of you. YES you can move/rename a file with all three options you mention. Which would be apparent from reading the docs, and has been made abundantly *more* apparent via this question. What more info are you wanting?

Comment: @AdamCameron just want to find out if there are any hidden subtle differences.  It's never obvious in CFML <-> CFScript world, like I just found out yesterday that `<cfimage action="info"> != ImageInfo()`.

Comment: @Henry: fair enough. Did you raise the image stuff anywhere? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @AdamCameron Oops, I meant to use `<cfdirectory action="list"> != directoryList()` as the example.  `Type` attribute is missing in the function.

Comment: Ah yes. I chided Adobe at the time for that, but they didn't listen.